# bootstrap css data load

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic-content

i am using bootstrap framework for college project

i have data 50+

```
<div class="span12">
   <div class="span4">
         --- data ---
   </div>

<div class="span4">
         --- data ---
   </div>

<div class="span4">
         --- data ---
   </div>

</div>
```

i want that every row only 3 data. after three data it will create new row ie new

```
<div class="span12">
```

i am not able to do it dynamically plz help.

i tried this but didnt worked

```
if(mysql_num_rows($country)>0)
   {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($country))
 {
      $c=0;
      echo "<div class='span12'>";

   if($c==0 || $c==1 || $c==2)
  {
      echo "<div class='span4'>".$row['countryName']."</div>";
      $c++;
   }
   else
   {
     echo "</div>";
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: You need to clarify your question and clean up the code you posted. The PHP formatting is a mess.

Comment: which part of the code is not working for you

Comment: @Vadim.G just want that every row should load only three data. after that new row should get crate .. may be in my code my implementation logic is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($country)>0)
   {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($country))
 {
      $c=0;
      echo "<div class='span12'>";

   if($c==0 || $c==1 || $c==2)
  {
      echo "<div class='span4'>".$row['countryName']."</div>";
      $c++;
   }
   else
   {
     echo "</div>";
   }
 }

}
```

You are setting $c back to 0 everytime. Try my below code:

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($country)>0)
       {
$c=0;
          echo "<div class='span12'>";
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($country))
     {
          $c++;

       if($c % 3)
      {
 echo "<div class='span4'>".$row['countryName']."</div>";
          $c++;
       }
       else
       {
          echo "<div class='span4'>".$row['countryName']."</div>";
          $c++;
         echo "</div>";
       }
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that this logic will work much better

```
$row_num = mysql_num_rows($country);
if($row_num > 0)
{
    for ($i=0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($country); $i++)
    {
        $res_array[$i] = $row;
    }

    $i--;
    while($i > 3)
    {
        echo "<div class='span12'>";
        echo "<div class='span4'>". $row[$i]['countryName'] ."</div>";
        echo "<div class='span4'>". $row[$i+1]['countryName'] ."</div>";
        echo "<div class='span4'>". $row[$i+2]['countryName'] ."</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        $row_num += 3;      
    }

    echo "<div class='span12'>";
    if ($i > 0) 
    {
        echo "<div class='span12'>";
        echo "<div class='span4'>". $row[$i]['countryName'] ."</div>";
        $i--;
        if ($i > 0) 
        {
            echo "<div class='span4'>". $row[$i]['countryName'] ."</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Good luck